# How to draw grid in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, chakra-ui

```
const cell = <GridItem colSpan={1} rowSpan={1} bg="papayawhip" />

export const Board = () => {
  return (
    <div className="scaffold">
      <Grid
        h="500px"
        templateRows="repeat(50, 1fr)"
        templateColumns="repeat(50, 1fr)"
        gap={1}
      >
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        {drawGrid()}
        .
        .
        .
      </Grid>
    </div>
  )
}

const drawGrid = () => {
  return Array.apply(null, { length: 50 }).map((e, i) => cell)
}
```

Here I have create a cell. I have drawn the columns for that cell by drawGrid(), I need 50 rows as well but I don't want to call it 50 times. How should I implement it?

Comment: you mean 50 row ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check out this link. You can map it directly in the return or set a constant variable then call it anywhere you want.

https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-violet-8g5o2o?file=/src/App.js